# Sending data from custom wordpress form to custom table not working

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I seem to have a problem with my php code. I created a template on wordpress and put in a php script that collects data from users and sends it to a custom table in the database. Unfortunately, for some reason the code isn't working and I don't know why.

Upon filling the form, the "your application has been submitted" statement is echoed but for some reason the information entered is still not being sent to the database. Initially data captured from the form was being sent to the table, until i added new columns to the database table and modified this bit of code to match the changes made in the database. Everything checks out. the table (jobs) and column names in the db are exactly as you see them in this code.

Your assistance will much appreciated.

### code bit

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

global $wpdb;
$positiondesired=$_POST['positiondesired'];
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$secondname=$_POST['secondname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phonenumber=$_POST['phonenumber'];
$highschoolgrade=$_POST['highschoolgrade'];
$unicourse=$_POST['unicourse'];
$unigrade=$_POST['unigrade'];
$salary=$_POST['salary'];
$skills=$_POST['skills'];
$applicationletter=$_POST['applicationletter'];


$wpdb->insert( 'jobs', array( 'firstname' => '$firstname', 'secondname'  => '$secondname', 'email' => '$email', 'phonenumber' => '$phonenumber', 'highschool_grade' => '$highschoolgrade', 'uni_course' => '$unicourse', 'uni_grade' => '$unigrade', 'salary' => '$salary', 'skills' => '$skills', 'applicationletter' => '$applicationletter', 'postion' => '$positiondesired' ), array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' ) );

echo '<h3 style="color:green;">Your application has been submitted</h3>';
} 
?>
```

### The fields indicated in the code match the ones in my table

Answer (score 0):

```
try like this 
enter code here    $wpdb->insert( 'jobs', array( 'firstname' => $firstname , .... ),
     array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' )   );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. i have tried that (removing the single quotes from the variables). Upon filling the form, the "your application has been submitted" statement is echoed but for some reason the information entered is still not being sent to the database. Initially data captured from the form was being sent to the table, until i added new columns to the database table and modified this bit of code to match the changes made in the database. Everything checks out. the table (jobs) and column names in the db are exactly as you see them in this code. still its not working. your thoughts?